# How can I create an array with key value and set new state?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a `values` state. It's an empty array.

On componentDidMount I take values from API, this action set new state with an array like this:

```
 [
   435235324: { data: ... },
   456565767: { data: ... }
 ]
```

Each number is an id.

I have websocket for new data in each id, So I need update data value of array item.

My search function is:

```
const setNewValueToState = (id, data) => {
    const exist = widgetValues[id];
    console.log(exist)
    if(!exist){
      setWidgetValues(oldValues => [...oldValues, oldValues.id = data ])
    }
  }
```

I need to check if id exist on array, if not, "push it" on.

But it doesn't work. It return an infinite array like this:

```
[
 { data: ... },
 { data: ... }
]
```

An array without key :/

Comment: Could you fix the question? `[id1: {}, id2: {}]` is not a valid data structure. It can either be `[{}, {}]` or `{id1: {}, id2: {}}`.

Comment: Based on your syntax above, I think you mean to say that the new state is setting an *object*, not an array:

`{
   435235324: { data: ... },
   456565767: { data: ... }
 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [
   435235324: { data: ... },
   456565767: { data: ... }
 ]
```

Is not a valid array structure, as the others comments say, you should use an array of objects

```
[ 
   { 
      "id":123456,
      "data":{ 
         ....
      }
   },
   { 
      "id":1234567,
      "data":{ 
         ....
      }
   },
]
```

Or use an object

```
{
     123:{
         data:{}
     },
     1234:{
         data:{}
     },

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your state looks like this:

```
[{id: '123', data: ...}]
```

This is **not** a valid data structure:

```
[123: {data ...}]
```

```js
let data = [{
  id: 993,
  data: 'foo'
}, {
  id: 123,
  data: 'bar'
}];

let idToSearch = 123;

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].id = idToSearch) {
    // found it, it's data[i]
    console.log('Found:', data[i]);
    break; // exit the loop!
  }
}
```

Or new hot stuff which I tend to avoid because I usually work with very big datasets and every `ms` counts (invokes a callback for each index). But it's totally fine with small or medium arrays in most environments:

```
const found = data.find(item => item.id === idToSearch);
```

Comment: my state it isn't a map? https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-data-structures-map/

Comment: If it's really a Map, I don't think you can use `data[index]` to access it. Use `data.get(index)` and `data.set(index, value)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @Drusto 's answer. The array structure is not correct. it should be

```
var oldObj = {
    435235324: {},
   456565767: {}
};
```

And finally you can do

```
var newObj = {...oldObj, 435235324:{yourKey: "yourVal"}}
```

Also your **setWidgetValues** I need to see.

Comment: setWidgetValues its a Hook setState method to set that